# Как обработать API и вывести в шаблон проверку лайков

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

Здравствуйте, прикрутил себе лайки по этому гайду:
http://apirobot.me/posts/how-to-implement-liking-in-django

Но я не знаю как вывести в шаблон проверку поставил ли пользователь лайк, не знаю к чему обращаться. Сам полный нуб, только учусь.

Answer (score -1):

Не совсем понятно, что значит "обработать API". Если Вы используете REST, значит, выводить данные в шаблон нужно после запроса к API. Делается это через Ajax, при помощи jQuery, например. В скрипте отправляете запрос на Ваш эндпойнт, получаете ответ с необходимой инфомацией. Потом его как-то обрабатываете и добавляете на страницу, опять же, в скрипте.